# Alter default settings for cowplot theme

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I like the default theme for `cowplot`, but I want to make some alterations.  For example, I'd like to be able to adjust the default for `legend.key`.  A MWE,

```
library(ggplot2); library(cowplot)

plt = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, color = factor(cyl))) + geom_point() + theme(legend.key = element_rect(color = 'black'))

plt
```

However, this doesn't work.
[image]

Is there any way of adjusting the `cowplot` theme without having to redefine the whole dang thing manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cowplot` theme sets the default linetype of rects to 0, which means 'transparent':

```
rect = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA, color = NA, size = 0, linetype = 0)
```

Overriding that default give you what you want:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, color = factor(cyl))) + 
    geom_point() + 
    theme(legend.key = element_rect(color = 'black', linetype = 1))
```

[image]